# getting error message as cannot execute [Permission denied] for below code . it is giving me the expected string part but along with error

Tags: shell

I am getting error message as ./array.sh[8]: feed_name1=PAYDET: cannot execute [Permission denied] for below code . it is giving me the expected string part but along with error. please help

```
#!/bin/ksh
cd /data/transfer/output
files=(`ls -1t | head -6`)
echo ${files[@]}

for ((i=0, j=1; i< ${#files[@]}; i++, j++)); do
 echo  "feed$j"="${files[$i]}"
     feed_name"$j"=$(echo "${files[$i]}" |  cut -f3 -d'_' | cut -f2 -d'-')
 done
```

Comment: `feed_name"$j"=blah` is not a variable assignment.  Assuming the variable j is unset (so `$j` is the empty string), when bash sees `feed_name"$j"=blah` it attempts to run a command named `feed_name=blah`. I would expect the error to be "command not found" rather than "permission denied".

Comment: If you want to make it a variable assignment, you could do `eval feed_name"$j"=....`, but there are better ways to accomplish your goal.